# Convert columns to rows oracle version 1.5.5 based on dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have my sample table as below:

```
Date            Product  Member_code
01/01/2015      ABC       1A
01/02/2016      BBB       1A
12/04/2013      SCC       2C
12/04/2014      AQQ       2C
```

Expected Result

```
Member_code   Old_product       New_product
 1A             ABC               BBB
 2C             SCC               AQQ
```

thanks for your help in advance
cheers

Comment: I think you mean oracle sql developer 1.5.  unlikely you are using version 1 of oracle. it is probably 12c or 11g. in addition you probably want the Pivot function.  Also your code is kind of unreadable try using http://sqlfiddle.com/ to set up your question

Comment: There never even was (official) Oracle database version 1. Larry Ellison said that *who would buy something that is version 1?*, so Oracle started from version 2

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way to capture the oldest and the newest values in the `product` column is with the `first / last` aggregate function. (Personal observation: there are many practitioners, even advanced ones, who avoid this aggregate function - for reasons I don't understand.)

Using Kaushik Nayak's setup (`CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements):

```
select   member_code,
         min(product) keep (dense_rank first order by p_date) as old_product,
         min(product) keep (dense_rank last  order by p_date) as new_product
from     yourtable
group by member_code
;

MEMBER_CODE  OLD_PRODUCT  NEW_PRODUCT
-----------  -----------  -----------
1A           ABC          BBB
2C           SCC          AQQ
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `SELF JOIN`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7187d0/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable
    (p_Date varchar2(10), Product varchar2(3), Member_code varchar2(2))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO yourtable (p_Date, Product, Member_code)
         VALUES ('2015-01-01', 'ABC', '1A')
    INTO yourtable (p_Date, Product, Member_code)
         VALUES ('2016-02-01', 'BBB', '1A')
    INTO yourtable (p_Date, Product, Member_code)
         VALUES ('2013-04-12', 'SCC', '2C')
    INTO yourtable (p_Date, Product, Member_code)
         VALUES ('2014-04-12', 'AQQ', '2C')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
 SELECT t1.member_code,
       t1.product old_product,
       t2.product new_product
FROM   yourtable t1
       join yourtable t2
         ON t1.member_code = t2.member_code
            AND t1.p_date < t2.p_date
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7187d0/2/0)**:

```
| MEMBER_CODE | OLD_PRODUCT | NEW_PRODUCT |
|-------------|-------------|-------------|
|          1A |         ABC |         BBB |
|          2C |         SCC |         AQQ |
```

Comment: "Need to" is too strong; one does not **need** to use a self-join for this problem.

Comment: @mathguy : noted